# Did ASP.Net AJAX make it into WSS3/MOSS Service Pack 1?

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-ajax, moss

There were a lot of promises and hopes, but did MS actually get around to including ASP.Net AJAX in either WSS3 SP1 or MOSS SP1?  None of the release notes mention it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ASP.Net AJAX is not included in either Service Pack.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net AJAX was included with .net 3.5.

As far as I remember it wasn't included in WSS3 or MOSS SP1.

BTW WSS3 & MOSS SP2 is now out (and I don't believe it was included in that either.)

It's not that hard to get setup, you just need to make some interesting additions to your web.config, and master pages.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience ASP.NET AJAX must be installed by itself (it hasn't been included in anything I have installed). [Here is the download link](http://www.asp.net/ajax/downloads/) for the installer.

Follow [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/MossAjaxWebPart.aspx) to get it loaded into the SharePoint web.config files.